# Google Colab Git-Annex Update Issue

Tags: git-annex

I am trying to use Google Colab for a fMRI experiment, however, I have been struggling with incompatibilities between package versions (for datalad). At first, git did not update with sudo-apt get and I found the solution with this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
git --version
```

Even though git is updated, git-annex does not seem to update, whilst trying to update with this

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y git-annex
```

it gives this error:
"git-annex is already the newest version (6.20180227-1)." But the dependency for datalad requires git-annex at least to be 8.

The git configuration is already initiated (user name and email).

I would deeply appreciate any opinions on how to fix this issue.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Python package `datalad-installer` (https://pypi.org/project/datalad-installer). It provides more methods to install git-annex (`datalad-installer git-annex -m <method-name>`), see [the README](https://github.com/datalad/datalad-installer/#git-annex) for an overview of methods, e.g., a conda-based installation, or a git-annex autobuild. Alternatively, if you are working with a conda environment, installing datalad via conda will automatically pull in a recent-enough version of git-annex (see http://handbook.datalad.org/en/latest/intro/installation.html#conda)